# Problema con tiempo de expiración (Sistema de autentificación y autorización)

Tags: c#, html5, mvc

Me encuentro trabajando en una aplicación Web, la cual se tiene **un sistema de autentificación y autorización** (Modulo de seguridad).

En este modulo de seguridad, se genera un **Token**, la cual contiene la información del usuario y un tiempo de expiración (30 minutos), así mismo el tiempo se reinicia cada vez que el usuario realice una acción (Controlador).

Cabe mencionar que dicha aplicación Web requiere llenar grandes formularios, lo cual para obtener dichos datos requiere un tiempo promedio de 30 a 40 Minutos (En usuarios nuevos).

Por lo cual unos de los problemas que se tiene, es que los usuarios pierden todos los datos necesario para llenar los grandes formularios, debido que se acaba su tiempo de expiración, y lo redirige a la vista de login.

Se han planteado varias soluciones para resolver dicho problema, como por ejemplo:

- Almacenar en la caché del navegador, los datos del formulario.
- Crear una notificación de alerta, la cual notifique al usuario que su sesión esta por expirar (Se mostrará dicha notificación, 3 minutos antes que se acabe la sesión), por lo cual le dará una opción al usuario de actualizar su tiempo de expiración.
- Cada evento como click o key press, estará actualizando el tiempo de expiración (Sin embargo no se recomienda, debido que dicha aplicación web lo estará utilizando muchas personas, y eso generará varias llamadas al server).
- Aumentar el tiempo de expiración (No se quiere implementar, dado que se pierde el control del módulo de seguridad, del sistema).

> ¿Qué recomendaría ustedes para solucionar dicho problema?

Gracias por leer la pregunta, y espero sus respuestas.

Saludos.

Comment: Porque no hacen registros escalables , a que me refiero que hay etapas de registro y que cada ves que seguarde una etapa del registro se cree otro token y pueda seguir llenando los datos

Comment: @DiegoGuerrero de hecho es un pregunta que puede compartir cualquier respuesta (Ya que existe varias manera de implementa), y me gustaría conocer que han hecho los otros developer para problemas similares.

Comment: @steven Gracias a tu respuesta, de hecho se implemento algo así. Del lado del cliente implementamos un socket que escucha el tiempo de conexion, y definimos una politica  de tiempo, cuando falte 5 minutos de vencimiento, se le enviará una alerta al cliente para que renueve el token, en caso que no lo renueve se le redirigen automaticamente al login (Por lo cual hacemos conciencia a los clientes del tiempo de conexión).

Answer (score 1):

Listo, el problema que tenía es que estaba usando el tiempo de expiración por defecto del ticket y aunque tenía seteada la cookie para que caducara en una semana, el ticket caducaba a la media hora, gracias!

```
        bool persist = true;
        var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie("usuario", persist);

        cookie.Name = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        cookie.Path = "/";

        var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
        var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), ticket.IsPersistent, correo);

        cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```